# How to get current URL requesting for network connection?

Tags: android

How can i get current URL requesting for network connection?
e.g. YouTube current running video URL, downloading a file URL from any app .

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  For good reason-  it would be a huge security hole if an app could send every URL back to a central server.  It would basically be made to order for malware.

Comment: but we can get all current URLs from webview then why we can't get it from apps?

Comment: You can't do that either.  You can get the current URL of a webview in your app.  You can't do that cross-app.